# How to set flags in Android WebView within App?

Tags: android, web, webview

I am trying to get the Sensor'infomation with WebView in App, as the offical's website, it show:to Get the sensor information, Need to set flags,but in the webView,how to use java ot kotlin to set flags;The relavte flags is shown as below!
[The flags that I want set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idQda.png)